# Python: How to plot time interval from a Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the a dataframe(`df`) which has the data of a Job being executed at different time intervals. It includes the following details about the execution of a job:

1. Job Start Time (`START`)
2. Job End Time (`END`)
3. Time Interval (`interval`) i.e., `END` - `START`.

A small part of dataframe is shown below.

**Dataframe(df):**

```
  END    |  START   |  interval
1423.0   |  1357.0  |    66.0
33277.0  |  33325.0 |   -48.0
42284.0  |  42250.0 |    34.0
53466.0  |  53218.0 |   248.0
62158.0  |  62073.0 |    85.0
```

I want to plot a graph with the `x-axis` as the timestamp and the `y-axis` with the `interval`. I tried to do it with the `START` time but it is not giving the correct result. How can we do this?

**Code**

```
fig_dims = (12, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_dims)

sns.lineplot(x = 'START', y = 'interval', data = df, ax = ax)
```

**Output**
[image]

**Required Output**
`x-axis` - Timestamp
`y-axis` - Interval

Comment: How does the current plot differ from your expected outcome?

Comment: The current plot cannot be used for infering anything as the range of timestamp is too large. Is there a better way to plot this data so that we can derive conclusions out of it?

Comment: Covert time to datetime index & resample, interpolate and plot that on x axis. [This is a really nice guide](https://machinelearningmastery.com/resample-interpolate-time-series-data-python/)